A superhero called Ratchet Man with a robot sidekick
What movie was it, in the 80s or 90s, where Ratchet Man and his trusty R-2 disarm a bomb, foil the bad guys, and save the day? 
R-2 was a robot, pretty sure in the movie he was named R-2. Ratchet Man is a repairman superhero, I believe he wore a green spandex costume with a wrench on his chest and called himself Ratchet Man. I think it starred Jaleel White.

ANY more details... perhaps in more common English? (I am not a native speaker, and I had to look up ratchet man, and I SUSPECT R2 refers to a Robot of some kind, as in R2D2?) Anyway, vague guess: "The Black Hole" or "Silent Running" ring a bell? At least they have R2'ish robots.

i think it stared Jaleel White

Then I am on completely the wrong track... so I suspect my interpretation of "r2" is totally wrong. As I somehow suspect I am not the only one who is lost at "r2", please explain what an r2 is to you? To do the same with "ratchet man" might be helpful :).

r2 was a robot pretty sure in the movie he was named r2 ratchet man is a repair man super hero i believe he wore a green spandex costume with a wrench on his chest and called himself ratchet man

You probably mean Blankman from 1994. It starred Damon Wayans as a nerdy repairman who becomes a superhero and he has a robot sidekick called J-5. They try to defuse several bombs in the movie, IIRC. But he had no ratchet on his chest and he wore a red outfit. Here's the trailer:




thats it! thank you yea i knew i would have details wrong i haven't seen this movie since i was a kid thanks again!
